# Can an SD card be hacked too?

Tags: sd-card

My old phone was hacked, is the SD card from that phone unsafe to use in my new phone? I am afraid there may be packages on it that are hidden that may get delivered to my new phone and corrupt it as well.

Comment: Why *not*? Any kind of storage can store malware on it, even those floppy disks...

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried, and if there is nothing important on the SD card, you can simply format it (remove everything on it).

That will get rid of any potential malware that could be on there. But it will also get rid of anything else you stored on there.

Edit: Did I get downvoted because it is theoretically possible to hack the microcontroller of an SD card? https://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=3592 It sure is, but the chance that it happened to OP is near zero. People who report their phone has been hacked have often simply installed a bit of malware.

Comment: I think it was a good answer and gave you your point back ;)

Comment: You didn’t receive a downvote but you also didn’t receive an upvote due to the meta commentary in your answer

Comment: @Ramhound Fair. Would you be so kind to take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1704355/how-do-i-set-up-my-own-web-server-website-for-my-home-network

Comment: @Gantendo - At the spam or the question.  Why am I looking at that question?

Comment: @Ramhound Hm, I wouldn't have recognized that as a spam seed (I had to look up that term!). Thanks!

Comment: @Gantendo - It received a spam answer within 25 minutes of it being asked and the question is low quality.  Almost 20 comments and it's not even close to being able to be answered

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah I can't see deleted answers unfortunately. I learned something new. Thanks.

Comment: Formatting does not remove everything. The boot sector and partitiining still remain in tact (even with a ffull format)  Malware could lurk in a hidden partition or the boot sector, but I'm highly skeptical it could be triggered on a typical Android system.